# How to unset the default printer when calling PrintDlg

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, printers

Does anyone know how to make Windows think there is no default printer? I have code that is out in the wild that gets printer default via a call to PrintDlg with the flags set to PD_RETURNDEFAULT:

```
  pdlg.Flags |= PD_RETURNDEFAULT
  e = PrintDlg(&pdlg);
```

If there is no default printer this call returns 0 and CommDlgExtendedError() returns 4104 (PDERR_NODEFAULTPRN). So I set the default printer to test this and now have no way to get the error code again and test my code! Arg.

Comment: Why you want to get the error code (PDERR_NODEFAULTPRN: A default printer does not exist.) again after you set the default printer?

Whether you want to tun off `Let Windows manage my default printer` ？ If so, you could try to modify the LegacyDefaultPrinterMode value to `1`.

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`

Comment: The issue is that some people don't have a default printer set.  The code uses settings from the default printer -- so I just want to handle this situation correctly.

Comment: Put your call to PrintDlg in a wrapper function, and then when you want to test your error handling code just make your wrapper return the same thing that PrintDlg would if there were no default.